# Netty : How to share ChannelHandleContext across loosely coupled services

Tags: netty, sharing, channel, loose-coupling

Working on an client server application where on server side I have a client facing service component which intercepts all the socket requests from clients and after scanning the message it routes to the different services through messaging bus, so they are loosely coupled.

Something like this:

[image]

Problem is once the services are done with the business logic, then need to send reply back to client but via "Request Handler Service" so all reply messages from all services are going through the single service component i.e. "Request Handler Service" since I don't have the ChannelHandleContext object reference with other services to send the reply back to client.

I was thinking to have a centralized distributed caching service (like memcached) to stored a mapping something like this (user Id -> session context (which is ChannelHandleContext from netty) but later I realized I can't do that since that requires serialization and this object does not support that so I have no other options except sending the reply back to "Request Handler Service" to communicate back to client.

What is the right approach in this case so that I can scale my application easily right now its really a big design issue.

Comment: Why did you roll back a useful edit that was made nearly two years ago?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by keeping a `Queue<Promise>` per upstream server, that marks the promises as complete with as result the response.

The solution to the problem would look like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34988353/1542723), but we need to edit some support for pipelining in the stream, so multiple routes are handles correctly.

Assuming your usecase is something like this:

```
+------------+                                         +------------+
|            |                                         |            |
|   client   |+--------+                        +----->|  upstream  |
|     1      |         |                        |      |      1     |
+------------+         |                        |      +------------+
                       |                        |
+------------+         |       +----------+     |      +------------+
|            |         |       |   this   |     |      |            |
|   client   +---------+------>|  server  |-----+----->|  upstream  |
|     2      |         |       |          |     |      |      2     |
+------------+         |       +----------+     |      +------------+
                       |                        |
+------------+         |                        |      +------------+
|            |         |                        |      |            |
|   client   +---------+                        +----->|  upstream  |
|     3      |                                         |      3     |
+------------+                                         +------------+
```

We need to make sure the following points are met when implementing this:

- If we are allowing pipelining of request (recommend for performance), we need either a way of identifying the requests using for example sequence numbers, or we need to de fragment the packets to come in the correct order.
- We need a way to send a timeout response to a client if a upstream timeout

We are going to assume the protocol doesn't have any packet sequence numbers, as that is the hardest case to solve.

Assuming the "Request Handler Service" has been written with support for high amount of request in mind, it has methods that can be called with some callback.

Provided your "Request Handler Service" has a api implementation that looks like the following:

```java
public interface RequestHandlerService {
    public default Future<Response> callMethod(Command cmd) {
        return callMethod(cmd, promise);
    }
    public Future<Response> callMethod(Command cmd, Promise promise);
}

public interface ServerSelector {
    public RequestHandlerService selectNextServer(Command cmd);
}

public interface Command {
    // ....
}

public interface Response {
    // ....
}
```

<sup>The above system is generic enough to be used for almost all kind of api's, a method to quickly implement, even if the system above that doesn't support passing around the callback class, as seen in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34878254/1542723) answer that does it for a Netty connection.</sup>

### Basic handler skeleton

We can make the following handler to handle the requests from our client:

```java
public class UpstreamDispachHandler extends SimpleInboundHandler<String> {
    private final static int MAX_PIPELINED_REQUESTS = 32;
    private final ServerSelector servers;
    private final ArrayDeque<Future<Response>> messageList = 
                  new ArrayDeque<>(MAX_PIPELINED_REQUESTS);
    protected ChannelHandlerContext ctx;

    public UpstreamDispachHandler (ServerSelector servers) {
        this.servers = servers;
    }

    public void channelRegistered(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

    // The following is called messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext, Command) in Netty 5.0
    @Override
    public void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Command msg) {
        if(messageList.size() >= MAX_PIPELINED_REQUESTS) {
            // Fast fail if the max requests is exceeded
            ctx.writeAndFlush(new FailedResponse(msg));
            return;
        }
        RequestHandlerService nextServer = servers.selectNextServer(msg);
        if (nextServer == null) {
             // Fast fail if the max requests is exceeded
            ctx.writeAndFlush(new FailedResponse(msg));
            return;
        }
        sendCommandUpstream(msg, nextServer);
    }
}
```

The above code declares the constructor and our used variables, we are using a [`ArrayDeque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html) as a temporary storage for our responsed, to make sure the order is kept.

We are now defining `sendCommandUpstream(Command, RequestHandlerService)` to add the request to the queue, and passing it upstream.

```java
private void sendCommandUpstream(Command cmd, RequestHandlerService nextServer) {
    synchronized(messageList) {
        messageList.add(nextServer.callMethod(cmd, ctx.executor().newPromise()
                    .addListener(f->recalculatePendingReplies())));
    }
}
```

The reason we are synchronizing over `messageList`, instead of using a `Queue` that has internal synchronization support, is to make sure some of our future operations are going to work correctly.

We are now at the last part of the client-server part of the software, making sure the replies are routed back in the correct order. To do this, we are [peek](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html#peek())ing at the head of the `Queue` to check if that `Future` [isdone](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#isDone()). If the head is done, we can [`remove()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html#remove()) it, extract the `Response` from it, and send it back to the client, making sure we [`flush()`](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelHandlerContext.html#flush()) the pipeline after all the responses are send. For performance reasons we are only flushing at the end instead after every packet.

```java
private void recalculatePendingReplies() {
    boolean hasSendMessage = false;
    boolean interruped = false;
    synchronized(messageList) { 
        Future<Response> elm = messageList.peek();
        while (elm != null && elm.isDone()) {
            elm.remove();
            Response result;
            try {
                while(true) {
                    try {
                        result = elm.get();
                        break;
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        interrupted = true;
                    }
                }
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                // Do something better with e
                e.printStackTrace();
                result = new FailedResponse();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                // Task is cancelled
                result = new FailedResponse();
            }
            ctx.write(result);
            hasSendMessage = true;  
        }
        if(hasSendMessage)
            ctx.flush();
    }
    if(interrupted)
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
}
```

A few design patterns are used in the above code, for example, a boolean flag is used to store the thread's interrupted status, instead of swallowing the exception. Even in the case a InterruptedException is thrown (should never happen), it is properly handled.

### Adding support for request timeouts

Sometimes, we want to implement support for timeouts in our protocol, for example, if the upstream doesn't respond in x amount of time. A [`HashedWheelTimer`](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/util/HashedWheelTimer.html) is ideal for this kind of operation as its characteristic can be easily modified to fit a applications usage pattern.

> #### Tick Duration
>
> As described with 'approximated', this timer does not execute the scheduled TimerTask on time. HashedWheelTimer, on every tick, will check if there are any TimerTasks behind the schedule and execute them.
>   You can increase or decrease the accuracy of the execution timing by specifying smaller or larger tick duration in the constructor. In most network applications, I/O timeout does not need to be accurate. Therefore, the default tick duration is 100 milliseconds and you will not need to try different configurations in most cases.
>
> #### Ticks per Wheel (Wheel Size)
>
> HashedWheelTimer maintains a data structure called 'wheel'. To put simply, a wheel is a hash table of TimerTasks whose hash function is 'dead line of the task'. The default number of ticks per wheel (i.e. the size of the wheel) is 512. You could specify a larger value if you are going to schedule a lot of timeouts.

We define the following set of constants at the top of our program:

```java
private final static long TICK_DURATION = 100;
private final static int WHEEL_SIZE = 128;
private final static long DEFAULT_TASK_TIMEOUT = TICK_DURATION * DEFAULT_TASK_TIMEOUT;
private final static HashedWheelTimer timer = new HashedWheelTimer(
              Executors.defaultThreadFactory(),
              TICK_DURATION,
              TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
              WHEEL_SIZE);
```

Then we modify our `sendCommandUpstream` method to put schedule a time-out in the timer, so the tasks [`cancel()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#cancel(boolean)) is called. We can do this with the following:

```java
private void sendCommandUpstream(Command cmd, RequestHandlerService nextServer) {
    synchronized(messageList) {
        Future<Response> r = nextServer.callMethod(cmd, ctx.executor().newPromise()
                              .addListener(f->recalculatePendingReplies()));
        messageList.add(r);
        timer.newTimeout((Timeout timeout) -> {
            if (!r.isDone()) 
                r.cancel(true);
        }, DEFAULT_TASK_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }
}
```