# How to read Message in netty in other class

Tags: java, netty

I want to read a message at a specific position in an class other than `InboundHandler`. I can't find a way to read it expect in the `channelRead0` method, which is called from the netty framework.

For example:

```
context.writeMessage("message");
String msg = context.readMessage;
```

If this is not possible, how can I map a result, which I get in the `channelRead0` method to a specific call I made in another class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Netty framework is designed to be asynchronously driven. Using this analogy, it can handle large amount of connections with minimal threading usage. I you are creating an api that uses the netty framework to dispatch calls to a remote location, you should use the same analogy for your calls.

Instead of making your api return the value direct, make it return a [`Future<?>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) or a [`Promise<?>`](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/util/concurrent/Promise.html). There are different ways of implementing this system in your application, the simplest way is creating a custom handler that maps the incoming requests to the `Promise`s in a FIFO queue.

An example of this could be the following:

<sup>This is heavily based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34878254/1542723) answer that I submitted in the past.</sup>

We start with out handler that maps the requests to requests in our pipeline:

```java
public class MyLastHandler extends SimpleInboundHandler<String> {
    private final SynchronousQueue<Promise<String>> queue;

    public MyLastHandler (SynchronousQueue<Promise<String>> queue) {
        super();
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    // The following is called messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext, String) in 5.0.
    @Override
    public void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, String msg) {
        this.queue.remove().setSuccss(msg); 
        // Or setFailure(Throwable)
    }
}
```

We then need to have a method of sending the commands to a remote server:

```java
Channel channel = ....;
SynchronousQueue<Promise<String>> queue = ....;

public Future<String> sendCommandAsync(String command) {
    return sendCommandAsync(command, new DefaultPromise<>());
}

public Future<String> sendCommandAsync(String command, Promise<String> promise) {
    synchronized(channel) {
        queue.offer(promise);
        channel.write(command);
    }
    channel.flush();
}
```

After we have done our methods, we need a way to call it:

```java
sendCommandAsync("USER anonymous", 
    new DefaultPromise<>().addListener(
        (Future<String> f) -> {
            String response = f.get();
            if (response.startWidth("331")) {
                // do something
            }
            // etc
        }
    )
);
```

If the called would like to use our a api as a blocking call, he can also do that:

```java
String response = sendCommandAsync("USER anonymous").get();
if (response.startWidth("331")) {
    // do something
}
// etc
```

Notice that [`Future.get()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get--) can throw an [`InterruptedException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/InterruptedException.html) if the Thread state is interrupted, unlike a socket read operation, who can only be cancelled by some interaction on the socket. This exception should not be a problem in the `FutureListener`.

Comment: I'm glad there is C# with async/await.. what a horrendous way to write code